# Laravel Storage: Repeating "/Storage/" on foreach loop

Tags: php, laravel

I am uploading employee images to a report system built on Laravel, when i try to get the creator of a report comment line i am trying to bring back with it the employee picture. These pictures are stored in the database using the public path link. So when i convert it to the storage path using Storage::url() function i should get the storage link ready to display the image.

but this foreach loop is causing the /storage/ part of the path to be repeated inside the string for as many times the foreach loop runs.

any idea what might be going on?

this is my foreach loop:

```
foreach($report->lines as $line) {
 if($line->creator->employee->picture) {
  $line->creator->employee->picture = Storage::url($line->creator->employee->picture);
 }
}
```

creator is the relationship between user and report, employee is the profile of the user as an employee in the system, and the employee has a picture.

when I view the response data, I get this:

```
/storage//storage//storage//storage//storage//storage//storage//storage//storage/images/b9570720-bd02-4e66-957d-93574ad753b6.jpg
```

Comment: This seems fairly clear. `Storage::url()` will prepend "/storage" to the existing value. If you run it repeatedly on the same value, it will prepend it repeatedly. Why do you feel the need to assign this value in a loop?

Comment: well each line could have a different creator, a different employee that created the comment. I loop through the comment lines, and then change the value of "picture" to the storage value of that line

Comment: And what if it's not different? And why do you assume that the existing value isn't already a storage URL? You do understand that you're editing your database objects here, not just assigning a variable?

Comment: I may be wrong, but the "comment line" ($line) is always different, even if the creator is the same user. therefore there is always a user object as a creator in each line that is independent from one another. Also, i am not changing database object, i get a collection from the database but its the collection im modifying, i dont save the changes in the database. I assign a new value to the "picture" property of the "employee" in the variable $report, i never save the report to the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that you are assigning the transformed value right back to `$line->creator->employee->picture` looks like the culprit and an anti-pattern: the employee object's "picture" field will be assigned a value that isn't what is coming from the database.

You could avoid this by doing the transform to a URL where the value used (e.g. use `Storage::url(...)` in a blade file if that is where it is displayed) rather than in this loop. That avoids assigning the value back to the model, as it just uses the transform at the time of output.

You could also set a new property on the employee during this loop (e.g. `$line->creator->employee->picture_url = Storage::url(...)`) and then render that instead of changing the value of `picture`.

Alternatively you could just strip `/storage/` from the input: `Storage::url(Str::replaceFirst('/storage/', '/', $line->creator->employee->picture)));`. But this is still assigning a value to `picture` which doesn't seem like a good plan because your employee object is being changed for the sake of presentation.

Comment: sorry, I forgot to mention this: the transform to the URL (using Storage::url) in a blade file works perfectly. but i also have API requests and they need to have all the data already transformed to be displayed on an Ionic App. this is why i need the response to contain the /storage/ path

Comment: @BarBarBinks You should consider using Laravel's "API Resources" system for that.

Comment: @ceejayoz i will look into it, i am new to coding and every improvement helps

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [Erik Woods](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5135767/eric-woods) and [miken32](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1255289/miken32) you were both correct, I was under the impression that once you get the collection, that collection works more like an array, and has objects and relationships that are independent from each other so one line creator was different from another even when being the same id. I tested and learned that if you modify the "employee" of one line, where that employee is the same, that get's changed too, I though this only happened until you saved the changes a save().

What I ended up doing is this:

```
foreach($report->lines as $line) {
    if($creator = $line->creator) {
        if($employee = $creator->employee) {
            if($employee->picture && !strpos($employee->picture, 'storage')) {
                $line->creator->employee->picture = Storage::url($employee->picture);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am checking to see if the picture has already been converted to storage, before applying the change.

Any comments on this approach will be greatly welcome.

Comment: You can see this if you `dump()` a collection with multiple entries pointing to the same object; the repeated entries will just show a reference to the earlier entry. Objects are always passed by reference in PHP.

Comment: Note your solution relies on the magic string "storage" which may change, and also assumes that "storage" will appear nowhere in the file name. I would suggest that line be `if (str_starts_with($employee->picture ?? "", Storage::url(""))) {` which also gets rid of your existence check by using the null coalesce operator.

Comment: Thank you, I will apply this and will look into API Resources to chance the entire solution. :)